# TypeError: Error converting shape to a TensorShape: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: keras, keras-layer, autoencoder

I am trying to build an auto encoder for text using CNN in Keras, in Jupyter Notebook. I am working with IMDB data set which has 25,000 examples of 2 columns, one of review and of rating.
I first tokenized and converted them into sequences of numbers and padded up to 2340(max sequence length).
So, finally my matrix size is 25,000 x 2340.
Then I am trying to pass in Input layer, but I am not getting

```
input_ = Input((2340,)) 
Input(X_train)
```

Then I a, getting following error:

TypeError: Error converting shape to a TensorShape: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars.

Shape of X_train is (20000, 2340) after breaking it into train and validation set.

Kindly please explain why this error is coming.

Answer (score 1):

I feel the error is here Input(X_train), the function Input according to keras documentation expects a shape=(2340,) indicates that the expected input will be batches of 2340-dimensional vectors and it by default assumes the shape to be (None, 2340), so i dont think you need to pass Input(X_train) again. below is the example from keras documentation page

```
x = Input(shape=(32,))
y = Dense(16, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(x, y)
```

Hope this helps!!